# Scale along Z-axis only

Tags: transforms, axis

I was trying to scale this tilted cube along global z-axis:

[image]

I scaled it by twice with <kbd>S+Z</kbd>, the result ended up being:

[image]

I was baffled as clearly not only it scaled in z, but also in y.

Please help me comprehend this behavior. What does locking z-axis actually do? Why doesn't the result look more like:

[image]

?

Comment: Scale in object mode can not alter the inner geometry above along object axis. You should do that in edit mode or apply the rotation before scaling.

Comment: @RobinBetts, whatever the transform orientation is (here global Z), if the object is rotated (here 45 degrees) it won't become a diamond. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @lemon Crikey! Why's that? (Just goes to show I never scale in Object Mode) An explanation of why scaling the object's transform matrix in Z behaves this way would earn a UV from me.. unless _I'm_  missing something... why does the resulting scale include Y but not X?

Comment: @RobinBetts, answer provided... please, if I'm wrong, give yours (will learn something, really). Additional question: have you ever scaled in object mode, Robin? ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know object scale can only be done along its **own** axis (X, Y and Z).

So if we have this cube orientation (rotated 45 degrees around Y for instance):

[image]

it cannot be scaled in the global Z axis only.

That's why we have this result:

[image]

So to obtain the wanted diamong shape, you need to either:

- Apply rotation <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose 'rotation'. Then scale along global Z:

[image]

Or:

- Enter edit mode, then scale along global Z:

[image]

Comment: but... but... in object mode, it's scaling in 2 of its axes.. just not the one it has been rotated around. :( !  I'll have to multiply out some matrices by hand in the console to try and get my head around it. This must be _so_ basic.. and I've never noticed it!

Comment: You definitely can have a transformation matrix that scales in a diagonal direction, @RobinBetts. Just not in Blender.